# PostSharp build targets not running when using Debug configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, postsharp

I have setup a Visual Studio project that I have edited to reference the PostSharp build targets. I did not use the MSI installed to install PostSharp on my development machine.

The problem that I am having is that the PostSharp Targets are only executed when I change the build configuration to 'Release', but not in 'Debug'.

I can verify this by looking at the build output which includes the line when in Release:

```
PostSharp 1.5 [1.5.6.627] - Copyright (c) Gael Fraiteur, 2005-2009.
```

Looking at the project file, I do not see anything obvious that would suggest PostSharp would run with one configuration and not the other. How can I configure PostSharp to run during both Debug and Release configuration? Keeping in mind, I would rather avoid using the installer.

Karl

EDIT csproj snippent, appears at the bottom of file, below `<ItemGroup>`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DontImportPostSharp>True</DontImportPostSharp>
    <PostSharpDirectory>..\..\tools\postsharp-1.5.6.629</PostSharpDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(PostSharpDirectory)\PostSharp-1.5.targets" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the location of the `<Import>` element in the project file that imports PostSharp.targets.  There are normally three `<PropertyGroup>` elements in the project file.  One for general settings, one for Debug only settings and one for Release only settings.  Move the `<Import>` element if it is in the Release group, it should appear after the Import element for Microsoft.CSharp.targets.

Comment: I have defined a 4th PropertyGroup for PostSharp properties, and have the Import tag below the Import of Microsoft.CSharp.Targets. I will edit my question to show what it looks like

Comment: I dunno.  Switch msbuild output to Diagnostic to see what's happening.  Tools + Options, P&S, B&R.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was able to track down the problem. I had the build output path set to outside above the project root. I changed it back to the default 'bin\Debug', deleted the bin and obj directories and recompiled. MSbuild was skipping the PostSharp target beecause it thought the output files were up-to-date. The real strange issue here is that this was only a problem on Vista. Win XP, and 2003 Server did not have this problem. Thanks!